# Difference between SSL_set_connect_state and SSL_connect

Tags: c, openssl

I am just starting to learn openssl for C. I am having some trouble figuring out the difference between the `SSL_set_connect_state` function and the `SSL_connect` function as they seem to do thee same thing on my system. Could someone explain what the difference is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SSL_connect` invokes `SSL_do_handshake`, which performs the actual SSL handshake after invoking `SSL_set_connect_state`.

[Full function](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/64827f407b0b603f585d7fadfd7e61a60ed7a45b/ssl/ssl_lib.c#L1731):

```
int SSL_connect(SSL *s)
{
    if (s->handshake_func == NULL) {
        /* Not properly initialized yet */
        SSL_set_connect_state(s);
    }

    return SSL_do_handshake(s);
}
```